# Fragment Dragging and dropping inside a GridLayout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-fragments

I have searched over internet but unable to find out a good tutorial about Dragging and dropping of dynamic fragments where  user can see dragging of fragments too. Is this feature only for widgets? I am totally confused  so please help me cause I am unable to decide from where I should start.